# argument processing in shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a simple shell script which takes 2 argument (name and age),  assigns the argument to variable and prints the variable
If I pass only age value without name, the variable "vname" is assigned with age value
But I want to assign name to vname and age to vage.. In case if name is not passed them vname variable should not have any value.Can any one let me know how to implement this?

```
#!/bin/bash

vname=$1
vage=$2
echo $vname
echo $vage
```

Comment: You need to read the bash man page on how to determine the number of arguments (hint:  $#) etc.  This sounds like an elementary class assignment and your teacher ought to have provided you with some starting pointers.  Google "bash primer".

Comment: [Or read this excellent guide](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/).

Comment: This might help http://linuxconfig.org/bash-scripting-tutorial

Comment: "Excellent" is not a word I would use to describe the ABS.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash
echo $#
#### the number $# tests the number of arguments
## you can use it to create a loop or do the following 

if [[ $1 = *[[:digit:]]* ]]; then
 echo " Arg1  is numeric"
# assign Arg1 to age here .... (not coding for you)
else
 echo "Arg1 is not numeric"
     if [[ $2 = *[[:digit:]]* ]]; then
        echo " Arg2  is numeric"
  else
        echo "Arg2 is not numeric"
    fi
fi
```

I saved this code as "name_and_age.sh" and ran it:

```
./name_and_age.sh as 2
2
Arg1 is not numeric
 Arg2  is numeric
```

Comment: Have _you_ tested the code? your test will claim that `lol1` is numeric.

Comment: not a name, just an example of why your test is wrong. Your test only checks if the variable expands to a string that contains _at least_ one digit. That's not what I call _numeric_.

Comment: For me, a test to check if a variable expands to only numeric characters is (using extglob): `[[ $var = +([[:digit:]]) ]]`.